# How to make a copy of a linked list in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

This is my function to copy a list. The error is that it always copies the first element twice. What am I doing wrong?

```
Node *copy(Node *list) {

  Node *newlist, *p;

  p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newlist = p;

  while (list != NULL) {
      strcpy(p->airport, list->airport);
      p = p->next;
      p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      list = list->next;
  }

  return newlist;
}
```

Comment: This is already the third question about copying of linked lists today. Even the symbol names are the same. The name of this site is not www.domyhomework.com !!

Answer (score 3):

Break it out into 3 parts.

```
// Part 1 - the null list
if (list == NULL) return NULL;

// Part 2 - the head element
Node *newHead = malloc(sizeof(Node));
strcpy(newHead->airport, list->airport);

// Part 3 - the rest of the list
Node *p = newHead;
list = list->next;
while(list != NULL) {
    p->next = malloc(sizeof(Node);
    p=p->next;
    strcpy(p->airport, list->airport);
    list = list->next;
}
p->next = NULL;  // terminate last element.
```

Comment: The other answers are quite confusing compared to this one.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Node *copy(Node *list) {

  Node *newlist, *p, *prev;

  newlist = p = NULL;

  while (list != NULL) {
      p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
      strcpy(p->airport, list->airport);
      if (!newlist)
          newlist = p;
      else
          prev->next = p;
      prev = p;
      list = list->next;
  }
  prev->next = NULL;
  return newlist;
}
```

You need to keep a reference to the previous node to update its `next` in the next iteration.

Comment: Careful, when `list` is null `prev->next = NULL` will dereference an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of these lines

```
  p = p->next;
  p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

to

```
  p->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  p = p->next;
```

Comment: You are misleading. He will allocate memory for the head node twice, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Actually not @lekroif, im asking him to change the order of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

These lines cannot be right:

```
p = p->next;
p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

as that sets a new value of `p`, then overwrites it.

I suggest you put your `malloc` of the new node inside the `while` loop. You also need to set the `p->next` to something after allocation, and preserve a pointer to the first new node allocated.

Comment: No, Actually you're wrong.
Since he has the first element address of p, saved on newlist and allocated outside of while, he can alocate the next element, using p itself.
It just have to change the order of things:
     p->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      p = p->next;

Comment: @rfermi Well, technically the answer is not wrong. OP's code is. As written, this pair of lines makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node* copyList(struct node* source) {
    struct node* dest = NULL;

    while (source != NULL) {
        dest = insertBack(dest, source->data);
        source = source->next;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an indirect pointer so that each "next" pointer is modified during the loop, even if the list is empty. In other languages, you might do this by creating a dummy node whose "next" pointer equals the list's "head" pointer, but in C, all that's needed is a pointer to a pointer.

```
Node *copy(Node *list_node) {
    Node *new_list, **indirect;

    /* 
     * Every loop, "indirect" points to the following "next" pointer
     * that will be modified when we allocate a new Node. 
     */
    indirect = &new_list
    while (list_node != NULL) {
        Node *np;

        np = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        np->airport = strdup(list_node->airport);
        *indirect = np;
        indirect = &np->next;
        list_node = list_node->next;
    }
    /* 
     * At the end of the loop, terminate the linked list with
     * a NULL "next" pointer, which the variable "indirect" is pointing to
     * right after the loop ends.
     */
    *indirect = NULL;

    /*
     * The variable "new_list" is not uninitialized. 
     * Either it was modified through the pointer "indirect" during the loop.
     * or else the loop never ran, so it's null due to the above line of code.
     * Either it points to the start of the list or it's null, so return it.
     */
    return new_list;
}
```